# SOASTA CloudTest Lite ova VM does not start after import to VirtualBox w/ error: "Your cpu does not support long mode. Use a 32bit distribution."

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, virtualization

Trying to run some load tests on a website for performance comparisons. I downloaded the [SOASTA CloudTest Lite](http://www.soasta.com/products/cloudtest-lite/) VM (OVA file) because it runs up to 100 cloud-based zombies for free, has some rather nifty-looking graphy-things and a plugin to pull performance data from my server (on AWS).

It's set up to run on VMWare, but I already have VirtualBox and I really didn't want to install VMWare Player as well, since it has less features and would be redundant.

Using VirtualBox 4.3.10, I imported the ova. Shown as working [on the SOASTA forums here](http://soasta.lithium.com/t5/CloudTest-Technical-Articles/Running-CloudTest-Lite-on-Oracle-VirtualBox/ba-p/14617).

Booting in VirtualBox I get this error:

`Your cpu does not support long mode. Use a 32bit distribution.`

[image: Your cpu does not support long mode. Use a 32bit distribution]

3 seconds of Googling of course uncovers hundreds (maybe thousands!) of people trying to run 64-bit guests without hardware virtualization (VT-x) enabled.  Easy fix! But not so fast... My laptop has an i7-2720QM and I'm certain VT-x is enabled in my BIOS; to check my sanity, I open CPU-Z and it shows VT-x enabled. Also, VirtualBox has no problem letting me install a new 64-bit guest (it is limited to 32-bit guest installs if VT-x is not on.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wading through tens of googly results, I came across [this page on the virtualbox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=60734) which is not exactly my issue, but it does point out that an incorrect ***"Version" in the general tab settings*** can cause VirtualBox to throw this error.

Checking the settings I see it's set to ***Type: Other*** and ***Version: Other/Unknown***

Changing these to ***Type: Linux*** and ***Version: Linux 2.6 / 3.x*** allowed the VM to boot.

[image: Settings before]

[image: Settings after]